# jQuery event triggered on database table change/update/delete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, comet

I have a PHP page with a table that pulls data out of a MySQL database. The database is used by many users, via updates/edit or delete actions so it will be hard for the users using the table from the page mentioned to use it

For now, the users have to refresh the page to see if changes have been made, but refreshing the page will load the all application and not only the table. I could refresh the table at specific interval, but I am trying to make a responsive refresh. The goal is to refresh it only when the table from the database has been modified.
So I am using the jQuery setinterval and ajax to test if a table has been updated in the last 30-60 seconds, but still I don't think this is the best aproach.
Could someone come up with a better and useful ideea?

The mySQL query is:

```
SELECT UPDATE_TIME
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'shopper'
   AND TABLE_NAME = 'sh_partners'
```

And the jQuery timer:

```
   setInterval("updateContent();", 5000 );
   function updateContent()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'view/ajax/ajax.quickview.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#small tbody").html('<span class="wait">&nbsp;<img src="<?= DIR_MEDIA;?>img/ajax_loader.gif" alt="" /></span>');
            },  
            complete: function() {
            },                                  
            success: function(json) {
                refreshTable(); 
            }                           
        });                                                  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP typically involves a request-response type of communication - which means you would have to poll the server, as you are thinking. It sounds like what you want to do is have the server push to the client, which would require something like websockets.

Here's the wikipedia page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

Some more reading:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/start-using-html5-websockets-today--net-13270

Comment: could it be implemented using PHP?

Comment: I don't actively develop in PHP, but a google search for "PHP websockets" seems to have plenty of promising hits.

Comment: that is what I am doing right now, I also read about "comet" as a method for this, using push technology